# django ModelAdmin.fields + M2MField with a manually set 'through' model: development server vs. apache

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models, and a relation between them:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='PublicationPersonMembership')

class PublicationPersonMembership(models.Model):
   author=models.ForeignKey('Person')
   publication = models.Foreignkey('Publication')
   is_author = models.BooleanField()
```

The code above works and syncs without problem. I have defined then a model admin for the Publication class:

```
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', )}),
        (_('Extra'), {'fields': ('authors',)})
    )
```

I have a problem with the admin then: in localhost (django development server) I am getting a validation error as follows:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: 'PublicationAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' can't include the ManyToManyField field 'authors' because 'authors' manually specifies a 'through' model.
```

That's ok, I can cope with that although I would like to override this problem. But, here comes my real doubt, when I deploy this code on an Apache+WSGI server I don't get any error and the code runs smoothly. Why? Is there any difference in django validation depending on the stack?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the validation framework is not run automatically in production environments (apache + wsgi or equivalent).